# SQLite: How to get last record?

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database and want to get the last record.

I know of `ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1`. However, the reason that's not good enough is that this database A) has no indices and I don't want to create any, and no primary key either, B) is quite large, think of order 1bn rows.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    col1 TEXT,
    col2 float,
   )
```

Now, the rows are on the physical disk in the same order that they were inserted in, so getting the last one should be trivial. This order in MySQL would, I believe, correspond to the primary key which in MySQL always must be present, so I could use the `ORDER BY primary_key DESC LIMIT 1` solution. But here I don't know what to do because as far as I can tell there is no primary key that corresponds to the disk ordering.

I did a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table;` (which takes 15 minutes to run) and so I know the exact number of rows in the table, lets call it N. If I had an `AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` I could do `WHERE primary_key > N-1`, but again this seems to be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using this code:

```
select * from my_table order by rowid desc LIMIT 1
```

`rowid` is built-in field in `sqlite` tables
Read More : https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Comment: Bingo, thank you. I knew there had to be a way. Thanks for the link too.

Answer (score 0):

You always have an index unless you specify WITHOUT ROWID, that is there is a hidden column called **rowid** (AUTOINCREMENT which can only be coded when INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is specified) (INTEGER PRIMARY KEY defines the column as an alias of **rowid**) (AUTOINCREMENT imposes a constraint that the value, when generated by SQLite, is higher than any existing).

You could try to use ORDER by rowid BUT wuthout AUTOINCREMENT there isn't a guarantee that the highest **rowid** will be the last row (but until you hit 9223372036854775807 rows it should be (assuming you don't mess with the rowid)).

With AUTOINCREMENT you have additional overheads especially when inserting as it not only has to retrieve the highest rowid (which it typically adds 1 to) but it also has to retrieve the respective row from the sqlite_sequence table.
[SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So to be clear: I don't have AUTOINCREMENT, but if A) I don't delete, and B) I have fewer rows than that maximum, then `ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 1` will give the right result?

Comment: @ffppp yes as long as you also don't set/change the rowid. A VACUUM will reset the rowid values if there is no alias, so you might want to create an alias e.g. using `CREATE TABLE my_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  col1 TEXT, col2 float)`